# Delphi problems inserting a string, Incompatible types error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

```
procedure TTelephoneNumberConverter.btnConvertClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  number: string;
  dupe: string;
  converted: string;
begin
  number := edtInput.Text ;
  dupe := Copy(number, 4, 1) ;
  converted := Insert(dupe , number , 4 ) ;
  pnlOutput.Caption := converted;
end;
```

Ok guys I just have a quick question regarding Delphi 2010 and inserting strings into other strings. The purpose of this small piece of code is to take the 4th character in a specific string and to duplicate it and add it next to the specific character  e.g. 12345 -> 123445

The only problem is I keep getting an error :

> Incompatible types 'string' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'.

I am probably missing something small and stupid but would appreciate if someone could maybe answer my question.

Comment: *I am probably missing something*: You mean like the [System.Insert documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Insert) or the pop-up window that Code Insight gives you that tells you it's a procedure and not a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Insert`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Insert) is a procedure that modifies its second argument.

Its signature is:

```
procedure Insert(Source: string; var Dest: string; Index: Integer);
```

The compiler error you see occurs because `Insert` does not return anything and thus cannot be the rhs of an assignment.

Your code should therefore be:

```
converted := number;
Insert(dupe, converted, 4);
```

`Copy` is overkill for a single character. Use `[]` instead:

```
dupe := number[4];
```

Comment: Something to note is that if you are to use direct character indexing then you also need to add a length check to deal with a `number` less than 4 characters in length, to avoid the exception that `number[4]` will then result in.  *Copy* avoids this since it will simply return an empty string if the input string is shorter than the indicated start position resulting in a no-op when number is < 4 characters in length.  Adding those safeguards for an insignificant (in this case) efficiency gain is arguably greater overkill than simply leveraging the safeguards already built in to **Copy()**.